# Zoom-out Screen to view high res

Tags: windows, display, zoom

I have really small display and there are apps that take large space of Windows so it's really hard to navigate them.

I"m looking for a software to zoom out the entire screen so I can view these high res stuff.

I've searched software, but most of them can only zoom out what it zoomed in.

Comment: AFAIK on Windows 10 there is no way to zoom out below 100%

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm looking for third party software that accomplish what I want.  I am using Windows 8.

Comment: Have you try with Magnifier (standard windows software) and use `-` button from the app or from keyboard `Win + -`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I did and it doesn't allow me to zoom out less than 100%. Is there Win API that I can use? I'm sure there is. Looked all over on Google, but can't find anything.

Comment: From what i read you can only set higher screen resolution and scroll over the screen. I also did not found anything which can zoom out under 100% :(

Comment: @RomeoNinov Scrolling over screen is annoying. Guess then I will have to make a stackoverflow post.